# Pull updates from source repository

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on Github that is a fork of another repository. I made some changes, and they were pulled into the original repository, and more changes have been made there since then.

My forked repository is now out of date, and I want to make some more changes to it. Nothing has happened in my repository since the changes were pulled into the original, so it just needs to get all the new changes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained here: http://help.github.com/forking/